# Batch que chama "dtsx" não se conecta ao CMS Avaya

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch, ssis

Criei um serviço em `dtsx` que precisa se conectar ao `CMS Avaya`.

Acontece que quando rodo ele pelo Visual Studio ele segue o processo até o fim normalmente.

Mas quando chamo um `batch` ele não permite a autenticação.

Answer (score 1):

Você esta executando este DTSX por linha de comando no seu batch?
Se sim, passa os parametros de login e senha de acesso a base.
no DTExec, temos o /U --> User e /P -- Password

Se não for isso, pode postar o que esta aparecendo de erro.

[]´s

Comment: Olá Advaldo, obrigado pela ajuda.

Estou passando da seguinte forma:
dtexec /FILE "E:\SSIS\Principal_Prod.dtsx" /decrypt "[senha]" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EWCDI

[senha] = a minha senha para decriptação.

Comment: Tente isso:
dtexec /FILE "E:\SSIS\Principal_Prod.dtsx" /decrypt "[senha]" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EWCDI [senha] = a minha senha para decriptação /Rep

A única alteracao foi o parametro /Rep que gera um report (log). Veja o que ele gera de erro.